# iPhone automated: Setting order of tests in OCUnit or FoneMonkey

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, ocunit, sentestingkit

I'm using [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) for automation, which utilizes OCUnit (SenTestingKit) for programmatically writing test cases. Does anyone know if there's a way to define the order in which test scripts are run? And within each script, is there a way to determine when the test cases are run as well?

Answer (score 6):

It should be in alphabetical order of test suites, then within each suite, alphabetical order of test cases.